# What are the reasons to use a Visualforce page on Force.com Sites versus a @RestResource to accept incoming REST calls?

Tags: apexrest, twilio

I'm experimenting with an app that creates a new SMS record in Salesforce when an SMS comes in to a number in Twilio. It seems that there are two commonly accepted ways to do this:

1. Create a Force.com Site with a Visualforce page whose Apex controller handles the incoming REST.
2. Create a Force.com Site with a (public) custom @RestResource to handle the incoming REST.

It seems that the setup is largely the same in both cases: I would want to [verify the Twilio request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/security#validating-requests), use a permission set CRUD and other access permissions, etc.

The advantage to me seems to be to use a @RestResource, because it doesn't require creating Visualforce pages that have no content and just route the request to Apex. But most examples I've seen have gone the Visualforce page route -- even using multiple pages to accept different requests -- so I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing?

Comment: In case it's useful - here's the github Org for the code I created to use with Twilio...that uses a REST resource since it seemed easier to me...
https://github.com/britishboyindc/TextToCase_Twilio_Salesforce

Comment: Your example was the main one that I was looking at for @RestResource, in conjunction with Wade Wegner's post on anonymous APIs ( http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/ ). Thanks for that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically the ability to expose APIs as publicly accessible via sites wasn't very well known, which might have lead to a lot of REST-like visualforce pages by those simply ignorant of the neat feature hidden in sites.

Literacy has risen since then, and you can find examples of both, but if you see a lopsided number of historical posts that might well explain it.

The other possibly issue is that I believe, and will try to confirm later, that public API hits via sites count both as a site page view AND an API call. Since they're both metered resources it makes sense from a scalability perspective (and since we're cloud scalability mostly means money here) to use only one metered resource when possible.

Comment: That's a good point -- looks like someone else had the same question about the API call, as well as some additional ones: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46311/does-api-calls-to-apex-rest-service-published-on-a-public-force-com-site-come-un